# Eclipse: select [All configurations] by default

Tags: user-interface, configuration, eclipse-cdt

I often end up editing the Project Properties for the *[Active]* configuration by mistake, as it is the one selected by default when you open the Project Properties interface.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to have *[All configurations]* selected by default instead?

[image: The Project Properties interface]